# Call awaited database context methods in F#

Tags: asynchronous, f#, async-await, entity-framework-core

I have defined a context (inherited from DbContext) and in C# I use:

```
await _context.People.SingleOrDefaultAsync()
```

But having the context in the F# code, the *Async methods don't exist:

```
_context.People...
```

How can I call SingleOrDefaultAsync?

I am using Entity Framework Core.

This is my .fsproj:

```
 <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
   <PropertyGroup>
     <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
   </PropertyGroup>
   <ItemGroup>
     <Compile Include="PeopleQuery.fs" />
   </ItemGroup>
   <ItemGroup>
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.1.4" />
   </ItemGroup>
   <ItemGroup>
     <ProjectReference Include="..\Domain.People.csproj" />
   </ItemGroup>
 </Project>
```

Comment: Have you opened the `System.Data.Entity` namespace in your F# code? The `SingleOrDefaultAsync` is an extension method defined in that namespace, and extension methods are only available when you open the corresponding namespace.

Comment: @rmunn Using "open System.Data.Entity", it says "the namespace 'Entity' is not defined".

Comment: If you're getting "the namespace 'Entity' is not defined", you're probably missing a package reference in your project file. It might be helpful to edit your question and include your `.fsproj` file.

Comment: I had the wrong namespace in my first comment, since I hadn't realized that [EntityFrameworkCore uses the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.singleordefaultasync?view=efcore-2.0). So my first comment should have been "Have you opened the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` namespace in your F# code?" That's still the most likely candidate for resolving the issue: if the namespace isn't open, extension methods like `SingleOrDefaultAsync` won't be available.